# Create a 3D Object from cross-section by using THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, webgl

I've learned how to create shapes now and I want to take camera location and size information from the user and create a cross-section view.

I want to create a cylinder and get a cross-section. Can you tell me what I should research? where should i start?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you’re looking for is called “clippping” https://threejs.org/examples/?q=clip#webgl_clipping_stencil

Comment: I think no. This allows me to see the cross-section of an object. But I want to create a 3D object which has the cross-section view I determined with coordinate values. For example, I create and javascript object: {bototm: it's bottoms height, left: coordinate of the left side on X plane, width: width of the shape, height: height of the shape} I use this to create a rectangle. I create 3 or 4 rectangle objects like that and with these coordinates, which create a cross-section view. I want to create a 3D object which has that cross-section view.

Comment: i suggested the edit yesterday before you commented this, it just went through. sorry i still dont understand what you are trying to do

Comment: @EnesGiray The [ExtrudeGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry) looks like what you want, based on your comment.